# >5.0 lineWidth for a vtkImageTracerWidget?

Tags: vtk

Very simple question. I am trying to use a vtkImageTracerWidget to represent user input in my segmentation algorithm.  My inspiration for this widget choice was David Doria's code [here](https://github.com/daviddoria/ScribbleInteractorStyle).

In other words, the user draws on the image, and it acts basically as a brush, to seed the algorithm.

I am currently using the following code:

```
tracer->GetLineProperty()->SetLineWidth(20.0);
```

It works perfectly if I try to make the line width 1.0.  Or if I try to change the line color using SetColor() in the same manner.  However, I just cannot get it to make the line any wider than what seems to be 5.0.  I would like the user to use a big brush to make large, crude input.  The 5.0 vtkImageTracerWidget's line does not suffice.

How can I increase the size of the user input?  Is there perhaps another widget I should be using?  I checked the max line width, and it was on the order of 10^36, so that is clearly not the issue.

Thanks so much!

Comment: I can confirm that setting the line width to > 10 doesn't change anything. I'll look into it.

Comment: Goodwin Lawlor's answer here http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/Problem-with-vtkPolyLine-width-greater-than-20-tp5667414p5672819.html explains that this is an OpenGL limitation. I tried to verify that the max GL line width corresponds to the line width setting where the width stops changing, but was unsuccessful. I tried #include <GL/gl.h>     GLint smoothWidthRange[2];
    glGetIntegerv(GL_SMOOTH_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE, smoothWidthRange);
    std::cout << "GL_SMOOTH_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE: " << smoothWidthRange[0] << " " << smoothWidthRange[1] << std::endl; but the output is "1 0" which doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

Goodwin Lawlor's answer here http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/Problem-with-vtkPolyLine-width-greater-than-20-td5667414.html#a5672819 explains that this is an OpenGL limitation. You can  verify that the max GL line width corresponds to the line width by checking it (after there is a GL context, which means sometime after you've called   `renderWindowInteractor->Start()` ). For testing, you could do it in an interactor style event or similar) with:

```
// Initialize so we get these values back instead of garbage if the call doesn't work
GLfloat lineWidthRange[2];
lineWidthRange[0] = 123;
lineWidthRange[1] = 123;

glGetFloatv(GL_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE, lineWidthRange);

std::cout << "GL_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE: " << lineWidthRange[0] << " " << lineWidthRange[1] << std::endl;
```

On my hardware, this printed

```
GL_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE: 0.5 10
```

which indicated that 10 (as I saw experimentally) is the largest line that OpenGL will draw.

Comment: This will also depend on what OpenGL version/profile is used. Wide lines are marked as deprecated in the core profile, and therefore unavailable if a forward-compatible context with the core profile is used.

Comment: @RetoKoradi What are you supposed to use instead of "wide lines" if you want to draw a wide line :) ?